# Face error when I run react on swell "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Tags: reactjs

Hope you all are doing well. I am facing the error when I upload custom react theme on swell can anyone hep me to solve this error. For better understanding please check attached screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vho8T.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error. Errors are not displayed in the `Elements` tab. Check the [documentation about noscript tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript)

Comment: But my app is not working for this. Can you help me to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working for this"?